# How to connect to an existing document in Pyautocad?

Tags: python, autocad

I'm new to pyautocad and trying to work with an existing .dwg file open in a running instance of autoCAD.

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=False, visible = True)
acad.Application #this gives me an error
```

I cannot even get the active application instance. When I try to access the active application instance via `acad.Application` or `acad.app` I get an error:

`[WinError -2147221005] Invalid class sting`

Even the example [from the docs](https://pyautocad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) doesn't work.

```
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
acad.prompt("Hello, Autocad from Python\n")
print(acad.doc.Name)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another Python library I can use to interact with AutoCAD?

Answer (score 0):

You can try directly using comtypes modules as pyautocad itself is based on comtypes:

```
import win32com.client

acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")

acad.Visible = True
acadModel = acad.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace
```

You can also check [our blog](https://www.supplychaindataanalytics.com/category/pyautocad-en/) for more details.